# Viewing XS Cookie on Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, cookies, session-hijacking

I am able to view cookies using

```
javascript:alert(document.cookie)
```

But the problem is that not all cookies show up. Is there any way to read specific cookies, for instance the XS cookie using Javascript? It should have the same concept of working as this one does. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not. The Facebook `xs` cookie is set as HttpOnly, which causes it to be invisible to Javascript. This is an intentional security measure to protect the cookie from malicious scripts — it cannot be overridden by a script.